# LINQ to XML query and filtering names

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am working at Windows Phone 7 C#, XAML, XML and LINQ programming. I need to organize search by part of the name at following XML:

```
<Row>
  <Myday>23</Myday>
  <Mymonth>12</Mymonth>
  <Mynames>Alex, Joanna, Jim</Mynames>
</Row>

<Row>
  <Myday>24</Myday>
  <Mymonth>12</Mymonth>
  <Mynames>John, David</Mynames>
</Row>
```

I have following query:

```
var myData = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Row")
             where query.Element("Mynames").Value.Contains("Jo")
             select new Kalendars
                        {
                            Myday = (int)query.Element("Myday"),
                            Mymonth = (int)query.Element("Mymonth"),
                            Mynames = (string)query.Element("Mynames")
                        };
             listBoxSearch.ItemsSource = myData;
```

Query problem is, that it will return full part of the names like "Alex, Joanna, Jim" and "John, David". How can I get only Joanna and John? Second question is how it is possible to do that user enters `...Value.Contains("jo")` and query still returns Joanna and John?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to break apart that string to get the individual names.  In this case, something like this will be fine.

```cs
string line = "Alex, Joanna, Jim";
string[] names = line.Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var jos = from name in names
          where name.Contains("Jo")
          select name; // ["Joanna"]
```

Just work this into your query.

The original string contains the letters `"Jo"` so calling that function returns true.  It doesn't look at each of the words individually, just the string as a whole.

Comment: You should learn how to do proper XAML bindings. You're not meant to set the `ItemsSource` in the C#, but rather bind it in the XAML, to your ViewModel's `SearchNames` property

Comment: Claus, why it is not good to set the ItemSource in the C#? I took this lesson from [WP7 working with XML: reading, filtering and databinding](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-xml-reading-filtering-and-databinding). Can you suggest me some tutorials to read?